# SQL operand performing single row,column

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19gJ8.png)  **My sql query**:-

```
SELECT 
(s.Mark*0.8+((i.OutOf)*sum(i.Mark)/9000)+((ai.OutOf)*sum(ai.Mark) /180)+a.Mark)  
AS final 
from mark_semester s,
     mark_assignment ai,
     mark_internaltest i,
     mark_attendance a,
     master_student ms 
WHERE s.SubjectId=i.SubjectId and
      s.SubjectId=ai.SubjectId 
      and s.SubjectId=a.SubjectId 
      and s.SubjectId='1' 
      AND s.RegNo=i.RegNo 
      and s.RegNo=ai.RegNo 
      and s.RegNo=a.RegNo 
      and s.RegNo=ms.RegNo 
      and s.RegNo='100' 
      and s.Semester=i.Semester 
      and s.Semester=ai.Semester 
      and s.Semester=a.Semester 
      and s.Semester='1'
```

In this query i want to enter multiple `subjectids` and `regnos` to get data
can any one help me to solve this.

Comment: (1) *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  (2) I removed the incompatible database tags.  (3)  You don't have a question.

Comment: can u send me the modified query please

Comment: You can use IN clause   s.SubjectId in ('1','2',3') and same for Regno's

Comment: even though i am getting only 1output

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: i am using MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **IN** MySQL operator to handle multiple `SubjectId` and `RegNo`, like this:

```
SELECT (s.Mark*0.8+((i.OutOf)*sum(i.Mark)/9000)+((ai.OutOf)*sum(ai.Mark)/180)+a.Mark) AS final
from mark_semester s
    join mark_assignment ai on s.SubjectId=ai.SubjectId
    join mark_internaltest i on s.SubjectId=i.SubjectId
    join mark_attendance a on s.SubjectId=a.SubjectId
    join master_student ms on s.RegNo=ms.RegNo
WHERE
    s.SubjectId in ('1','2') AND
    s.RegNo in ('100','101') and
    s.Semester='1'
```

Comment: bro this code is good an optimized one on line 4 and 5 small corrections

Comment: you are selecting one column as `final` and you are working with `regNo.=100` that's why you getting result like that.

Comment: What you want as output ?

Comment: i want multiple subjectids and regnos

Comment: @MaheshMaf just try with modified answer

Comment: wrong output normal answer is 74 now it was 2004.14

Comment: its bcz you are calculating marks and you are making subject is dynamic that's why its gone wrong only you can make regNo. as multiple not both it will be a logical error not code error.

Comment: i read somewhere using functions in SQL the statement can return multiple it seems so hoping if anyone can help me out.

Comment: I think you need to post some sample data and an example result you're expecting